# Хранение типов данных в enum

Tags: kotlin, типы, enum

Необходимо в enum хранить типы данных. Хотелось бы получить что-то подобное:

```
enum class Names(val type : Type) {
    N1(Double), N2(Int)
}
```

Нужно это для того, чтобы в последствии можно было проводить такое сравнение:

```
fun checkType(name : Names, value : Number) = value is name.type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял, вам числа только нужны.
Вот так может быть:

```
enum class Names(val type : KClass<out Number>) {
    N1(Double::class), N2(Int::class)
}

fun checkType(name : Names, value : Number) : Boolean {
    return value::class == name.type
}
```

Comment: А как такое можно провернуть чтобы хранить типы и дженерики, например: LIST_DOUBLE(List<Double>::class), INT(Int::class)

Comment: Проверку делайте разветвленную, если тип List, то сравнивать надо по другому.

Comment: Нет, нет, мне не понятно как вот эту часть реализовать: ```enum class Names(val type : KClass<out Number>)```

Comment: Что общего у List и Number? Ничего. Наверное лучше так и не делать, но если очень надо, попробуйте Any.

Comment: Спасибо. Но тут я не правильно выразился, на самом деле мне нужно для других целей. Мне нужно знать при какой операции какой возвращается тип, что бы не делать приведение типов в слепую, Но похоже я просто не правильно мыслю. P.S. так не работает, я сразу попробовал: enum class Names(val type : KClass<out Any>) {GET_LIST_MY_TYPE(List<MyType>::class)}, может это делается как-то по другому?

Comment: С List<> проблема, как тут пишет создатель Котлина, у рантайма нет информации о типах дженериков. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154463/how-can-i-check-for-generic-type-in-kotlin/13166690

Comment: Спасибо. Значит в данном направлении решения нет. Пошел искать его в другом месте.